# Question related to bibliography research

Tags: support, on-topic-ness

Do you think that a question like "I am looking for papers in *this subject*" is valid for Academia StackExchange?

Examples:

- I am looking for papers and researches in Data Mining with Python
- I am looking for papers and researches in Big Data in Education
- I am looking for papers and researches in Open Data in Government

Comment: No, those questions are not in scope. They usually get closed reasonably quickly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the question is,

> What are some good methods for finding papers in my research area?

it's on-topic, but was probably asked already. Check the [literature-search](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/literature-search) tag for ideas.

If the question is,

> Can you suggest papers on subject X?

Then it is off-topic. This site is about research in general; it's not for domain-specific questions about your particular subject.

Comment: Great! Thank you for your answer. I will accept it as soon as it is available (~ in 10 min).